What's Shane the Dog of Miskatonia a reference to?
The director's commentary near the Shane the Dog quest in Miskatonia, says that Shane is a reference to something, but what?
Looking up the 1953 film, Shane doesn't show any similarities to show the quest / dog being a reference to the movie.
